# Package command line tool with Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unix, command-line

Disclaimer:  Cocoa newbie here.

I wrote an app with a Cocoa GUI that acts as a wrapper for a command line tool.  The problem is the tool does not come standard with OS X.  Thus, you have to install the command line tool first before using the Cocoa app, or else the app won't function.

Can anyone point me to some documentation (hopefully, with examples), that can teach me how to install the command line tool when the user installs the app?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to install this command line tool into the system bin directory so that it can be used from the command line independently of your GUI app? Or will your GUI app be the only way to run this command line tool?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Either way will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include your command line tool inside the bundle of your Cocoa app?  This way your Cocoa app is completely self-contained and the issue of "installing" the command line tool does not even arise.

Comment: Awesome.  Is this process documented somewhere like the Apple Dev site?

Comment: The Bundle Programming Guide should have more information. You could put your command-line tool in the Contents/MacOS directory inside your bundle (Table 2-5).  Then use bundlePath or a similar method to determine the path to your command-line tool.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW14